# Notify WinForm when a load process has ended

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a WinForms app with VS 2012, C# and .NET Framework 4.5.

I have a MainForm (WinForm) class and a class that connects to database a load data using a database Stored Procedure.

I have a `List<string> data;` and I need to notify MainForm when the load process has ended but I don't know how to do it.

I've thought to use a delegate like Objective-C but I'm not sure if I can do that.

**How can I notify MainForm when load process has ended?**

Comment: One way could be to use [`BackGroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) , load the data in DoWork and display a notification on Completed event.

Comment: How you are loading the data at the moment?

Comment: since u have the luxury of 4.5 check out await/async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => GetDateFromDatabase();
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => NotifyMainForm();
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```